# Deadlock on Bulk Delete, need better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, database-deadlocks

I am doing a bulk delete on a set of ID's as a string sent to a stored procedure separated by commas.  I have a function that splits these into a table so I can compare to them.  I sometimes get a deadlock on this SP even though I have `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`.  Is there a better way to do a bulk delete then this with a SP for performance and no deadlocks?

```
    DELETE FROM Game
            WHERE Id IN (
                SELECT g.Id 
                FROM Game g
                INNER JOIN [EventGame] eg ON g.Id = eg.Id
                INNER JOIN MemberEvent me ON me.EventId = eg.EventId
                WHERE 
                    eg.EventId = @EventId AND
                    g.Id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@DeletedGameIds, ',')) AND
                    (g.[Type] = 1 OR g.[Type] IS NULL) AND 
                    me.MemberId = @MemberId
)
```

Comment: Is this delete is on OLTP application delete is happening during application is online?

Comment: What is the Index on Id column on Game table?

Comment: Clustered Index, Primary Key

Answer (score 0):

Better way to delete is by identifying the list of id's to be deleted and then do a clustered index delete only thru id's.

```
CREATE Table #temp (Id Int)

Insert into #temp (Id) 
SELECT Id FROM Game
            WHERE Id IN (
                SELECT g.Id 
                FROM Game g
                INNER JOIN [EventGame] eg ON g.Id = eg.Id
                INNER JOIN MemberEvent me ON me.EventId = eg.EventId
                WHERE 
                    eg.EventId = @EventId AND
                    g.Id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@DeletedGameIds, ',')) AND
                    (g.[Type] = 1 OR g.[Type] IS NULL) AND 
                    me.MemberId = @MemberId
)

--you can do this delete in looping with batch size of 50000 records and use checkpoint
DELETE G
FROM Game G
Inner Join #temp t
ON G.ID = t.Id
--checkpoint
```

Comment: Ill try that.  Should I split my IDS into a temp table first or does using them in the Select have no effect either way.